# Will changing my backend systems or CMS hurt my search engine rankings?

Tags: seo, google, google-ranking, migration

What will happen to my website's search engine rankings if I change:

- CMS
- programming language
- framework
- database engine
- other programming-related stuff

For example, what if I change my website from WordPress to dedicate Ruby on Rails website or change it to DDN? Would doing this likely decrease my website rank?

Comment: See also: [How soon does site migration to new server reflect SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/92194/how-soon-does-site-migration-to-new-server-reflect-seo) and [Static HTML to Wordpress Migration SEO Implications?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28539/static-html-to-wordpress-migration-seo-implications) and [Site migration questions— PHP, link structure & SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/60742/site-migration-questions-php-link-structure-seo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you will plan well then you should be fine.

Key things in planning:

- URL management: You should build system so that old URLs should redirect to respective new ones. At least for those pages where you have a good ranking.
- If your new system can have as good or better user experience with similar content then you should be fine.

Let's understand by example:

Pages on Old CMS

> example.com
>
> example.com/inner-1
>
> example.com/inner-2

Pages on New CMS

> example.com
>
> example.com/web-inner-1
>
> example.com/web-inner-2

Now, you should try to have similar or better user experience on the new site.

- Load Time
- Navigation
- Content Placement
- Photos, Videos etc

And importantly, your old URLs must redirect (301) to respective new ones. Example:

> example.com/inner-1 => example.com/web-inner-1
>
> example.com/inner-2 => example.com/web-inner-2

If the planning may not be right then there will be maximum chances of the drop in ranking.

Comment: thank you for greate answer , so only urls are important part?  what if i completely has new URL Schema?? what if i change www.Site.com/news/NewsDetail.php?id=2 to www.Site.com/News/News-title-Url with same content??

Comment: @MoshheghFaghdan That and the resulting HTML. Most of what you mention is behind the scenes stuff which cannot be seen by a browser or search engine. If, for all intents and purposes, the site appears the same or close, all should be fine! Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc i mean change URL schema Schema decrease SEO rank?

Comment: Schema microdata has no impact on rankings.   At most Google uses schema to display the search results differently.   If you lose schema you might lose special display in the search results, but it shouldn't change your rankings.

Comment: @MoshheghFaghdan Changing the URLs will create a disruption unless you use a 301 redirect. Even then, I would keep this to a minimum as much as I can.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I think the OP just means changing URLs. Cheers!!